# Is a normal domain whose prime ideals are totally ordeded a valuation ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Recall one of the definition of a valuation ring is a domain whose ideals are totally ordered. (Then it will be a normal domain.) But if we restrict to all prime ideals the reverse is not true. The stalk at a non-normal closed point of a one-dimensional scheme is a counter-example. For example, $k[[x^2, x^3]]$  or $\mathbb{Z}_2[\sqrt{-3}]$. I just found that this has been already discussed in [Does totally ordered prime ideals in a domain imply valuation ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2813649/does-totally-ordered-prime-ideals-in-a-domain-imply-valuation-ring)

All counter-examples so far are non-normal rings, so the question in the title naturally appears.

Comment: I was going to point out example 2.1 of [Hedstrom, John, and Evan Houston. "Pseudo-valuation domains." Pacific journal of Mathematics 75.1 (1978): 137-147.](https://msp.org/pjm/1978/75-1/pjm-v75-n1-p11-s.pdf) , but user26857 has already posted an example of the same type.  You still may find the reference handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $L\subset K$ be a field extension such that $L$ is algebraically closed in $K$, and $R=L+XK[[X]]$ a subring of power series ring $K[[X]]$. Then $R$ is integrally closed, and it has only two prime ideals: $(0)$ and $XK[[X]]$, so its spectrum is totally ordered. It's not hard to show that $R$ is not a valuation ring.

Comment: Thanks. But my confusion is that I find $XR$ is also a prime ideal. Let $f\in R$. Then $f\equiv a+bX \bmod XR$, for some $a\in L, b\in K$. Now let $g=c+dX$ with $c\in L, d\in K$. Then if $0\equiv fg \bmod XR$, we have $a=0$ or $c=0$, and then we will find that $b\in L$ when $a=0$ for example. Hence $f\in XR$, which shows $XR$ is a prime.

Comment: You are certainly wrong! If $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ such that $X\in P$ then $XK[[X]]\subseteq P$. Let $f\in K[[X]]$. Then $(Xf)^2=X(Xf^2)\in XR$ and since $XR\subseteq P$ we get $Xf\in P$. (From this proof you can easily find a counterexample to your claim.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this, now everything is clear to me.